# How to programmatically get all neighbor cells info?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app with signal info and I want to have access in android libraries through which can see all the neighbor cells as the image I have below. Does anybody know how I can it?
I have tried the code below but the result it isn't that I want

```
List<NeighboringCellInfo> NeighboringList = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();

String stringNeighboring = "Lac  :  Cid  :  RSSI\n";
for(int i=0; i < NeighboringList.size(); i++){
    String dBm;
    int rssi = NeighboringList.get(i).getRssi();
    if(rssi == NeighboringCellInfo.UNKNOWN_RSSI){
        dBm = "Unknown RSSI";
    }else{
        dBm = String.valueOf(-113 + (2 * rssi)) + " dBm";
    }
    stringNeighboring = stringNeighboring + String.valueOf(NeighboringList.get(i).getLac()) +" : " + String.valueOf(NeighboringList.get(i).getCid()) +" : " + dBm +"\n";
}
```

[image: cells]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "I want to have access in android libraries through which can see all the neighbor cells"

Comment: @m0skit0 In the code that I have added I use `NeighboringCellInfo` library,if I say it right,  which probably is not correct. What I want is the method to have the same result as the image